# Finding the pdf of an estimator

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

We have a set of unidimensional data, $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ drawn from the positive reals. We define a model for its distribution:

The data are drawn from a uniform distribution on the interval $[0, b]$. This model
has a single positive real parameter, $0 < b$.

now consider the estimator:

$$\hat \mu = \frac{x^{(n)}(n+1)}{2n}$$

where $x^{(n)}$ is the $n^{th}$ order statistic in the distribution of $X_i$. How do I go about finding the pdf of this estimator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that the $N$th order statistic is less than $x$ is the joint probability of the union of mutually exclusive events where at least $k \geq N$ of the samples are less than $x$ but the remaining $n-k$ samples are greater than $x$ -- where there are ${n}\choose{k}$ different combinations satisfying this condition. The probaiblity of this union is a sum of probabilities for $k=N$ to $k=n$.

Assuming an iid sample of size $n$, the distribution function for $\hat{\mu}$ is

$$\mathbb{P} (\hat{\mu}\leq x) = \mathbb{P} (X_{(N)}\leq \frac{2nx}{n+1}) = \sum_{k=N}^{n} {{n}\choose{k}}\Big[F\Big(\frac{2nx}{n+1}\Big)\Big]^k\Big[1-F\Big(\frac{2nx}{n+1}\Big)\Big]^{n-k}$$ where F is the uniform distribution function

$$F(x) = \frac{x}{b} \ (0 \leq x \leq b)$$

Take the derivative with respect to x to find the density function.

$$f_{\hat{\mu}}(x) = n {{n-1}\choose{N-1}}\Big[\frac{2nx}{(n+1)b}\Big]^{N-1}\Big[1-\frac{2nx}{(n+1)b}\Big]^{n-N}\frac{2n}{(n+1)b}$$

You can prove that an order statistic distribution can be expressed as

$$\mathbb{P} (X_{(N)}\leq x)= F_{(N)}(x) = n {{n-1}\choose{N-1}}\int_{0}^{F(x)}t^{N-1}(1-t)^{n-N}dt$$

which makes the derivation of the density more apparent:

$$f_{(N)}(x)= F'_{(N)}(x)= n {{n-1}\choose{N-1}}\Big[F(x)\Big]^{N-1}\Big[1-F(x)\Big]^{n-N}f(x)$$

Comment: can you please also provide an intuitive explanation so as to how we arrived at the distribution function?

Comment: Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Yes that does make sense. But Is there any explanation for passing $2nx/(n+1)$ term into $F(x)$? Also Now if I try to find the expected value, I am guessing the integration bounds will not be $[0,b]$ any longer?

Comment: We have $\hat{\mu} \leq x$ iff $X_{(N)} \leq \frac{2nx}{(n+1)}$ because you rescaled the order statistic -- I am following your original notation where $n$ is the sample size and $N$ is the order statistic of interest.  You might just find the expected value of the unscaled order statistic and then multiply by the scale factor afterwards.  That would make it simpler.