# Finding expected value of mean of an estimator

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

We have a set of unidimensional data, $X_1, . . . , X_n$. : The data are drawn from a uniform distribution on the interval $[a, b]$. This model has two positive real parameters, a and b, such that $0 < a < b$. The idea is that we think about the joint distribution of MLE's $\hat a$ and $\hat b$. The joint pdf of the minimum and the maximum of a set of data drawn from pdf $f$, with cdf $F$, is:

$$f_{\hat a,\hat b}(x,y)=n(n-1)(F(y)-F(x))^{n-2}f(y)f(x)$$ Looking from here we can write the pdf down as (I hope I am not wrong here):
$$f_{\hat a,\hat b}(x,y)=\frac{n(n-1)(y-x)^{n-2}}{(b-a)^{n}}$$My question is how we go about finding the expected value of mean of this estimator from here on.

I know that the result should be $$E[\hat \mu]=\frac{a+b}{2}$$ But I cannot reach that.
I know how to get that for a pdf in one variable by integration. How do we approach this for two variables $x $ and $y$.

Comment: Which estimator? Are you after $E(\hat a)$ or $E(\hat b)$ or something else?

Comment: Expected value of mean, like I said. I am after $E(\hat \mu)$

Comment: ...Where you never defined $\hat\mu$. Cute.

Comment: Even I am having a hard time trying to adjust to these terminologies. Here is the problem set that I was trying to test myself upon. http://www.slideshare.net/adimanunited/ps1-v3-r 
Question 13 I was referring to.

Comment: where the hell is $\hat{\mu}$ defined?

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

The best one can do with this not-a-real-question is perhaps to *assume* that one is interested in
$$
\hat\mu=\frac{\hat a+\hat b}2.
$$
Then, by definition,
$$
E(\hat\mu)=\iint \frac{x+y}2\,f_{\hat a,\hat b}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy.
$$
Thus, the task is to check that, for every $a\lt b$,
$$
E(\hat\mu)=\frac{a+b}2,
$$
or, equivalently, that
$$
\int_a^b\int_x^b(x+y)\,(y-x)^{n-2}\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx=k\,(a+b)\,(b-a)^n,
$$
where
$$
k=\frac1{n(n-1)}.
$$
The change of variable $x=a+(b-a)u$, $y=a+(b-a)v$, reduces this to
$$
\int_0^1\int_u^1(2a+(b-a)(u+v))\,(v-u)^{n-2}\,\mathrm dv\,\mathrm du=k\,(a+b)=k\,(2a+(b-a)),
$$
which holds for every $(a,b)$ if and only if
$$
\int_0^1\int_u^1(v-u)^{n-2}\,\mathrm dv\,\mathrm du=k=\int_0^1\int_u^1(u+v)\,(v-u)^{n-2}\,\mathrm dv\,\mathrm du.
$$
Can you check these two identities?

Comment: Not a real question? Question 13 says "Write an expression for the expected value of $\hat \mu$ in terms of an integral." Now are you implying this problem set is wrong?

Comment: Yes, your question is not-a-real-question because you nowhere defined $\hat\mu$. Hence I had to **assume** a definition, and, provided my assumption is correct, I answered your question. See?

Comment: Compare with [your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/831355/), where you DEFINED $\hat\mu$.

Comment: I did not define that because it was not defined in the problem statement. Whereas in that other question, it was. This was supposed to be an independent estimator.

Comment: $$
E(\hat\mu)=\iint \frac{x+y}2\,f_{\hat a,\hat b}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy.
$$
why did you use the value (x+y)/2 here, is it a norm for calculating expected value when the pdf has two variables, or was that based on our supposed mean $\hat \mu$?

Comment: Once again: there is no definition of $\hat\mu$ in your post hence my answer starts with an EXPLICIT definition of $\hat\mu$, then the computation of $E(\hat\mu)$ UNDER THE CONDITION THAT $\hat\mu$ is defined accordingly. Now, for every function $H$, $$E(H(\hat a,\hat b))=\iint H(x,y)f_{\hat a,\hat b}(x,y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy.$$

Comment: Can't we find the mean of a distribution with pdf defined as $f(x)$ by finding the first moment, i.e.
$$
\mu=\int x f(x) \mathrm dx
$$ how will we go about finding mean for two variables x,y?

Comment: Of course we can (was this a rhetorical question?). To compute the expextation of the random variable $\hat\mu=H(\hat a,\hat b)$, the formula for $E(H(\hat a,\hat b))$ in my comment and the formula for $E(\hat\mu)$ in your comment yield the same result (only you don't have the density $f$ of $\hat\mu$ at hand, do you?).

Comment: Yeah I can "refer you to a source": MY POST. Did you even read it? Did you try to compute the two integrals at the end? Or are we just making noise with our mouths?

Comment: "the second one didn't" However it does. You might want to show your computations. "I was not comfortable with assuming μ in the beginning" If you have alternatives, please provide them.